# How should I set the valid bit of cache block to "1" for the first time in Gem5 without error?

Tags: gem5

I use classic cache. I want to copy certain data from one cache block to another cache block (in the same set). The valid bit in the destination block cache is zero. When I want to set the valid bit of the destination block to "1", I encounter this error message during the execution of the workload:

```
gem5.opt: build/ARM/base/statistics.hh:1055:
gem5::statistics::VectorBase<Derived, Stor>::Proxy
gem5::statistics::VectorBase<Derived, Stor>::operator[]
(gem5::statistics::off_type)
[with Derived = gem5::statistics::AverageVector;
Stor = gem5::statistics::AvgStor;
gem5::statistics::VectorBase<Derived, Stor>::Proxy =
gem5::statistics::ScalarProxy<gem5::statistics::AverageVector>;
gem5::statistics::off_type = unsigned int]: Assertion `index < size()' failed.
```

This error is related to the gem5/src/base/statistics.hh file:

```
Proxy operator[](off_type index){
   assert (index < size());
   return Proxy(this->self(), index);
}
```

I use the DerivO3CPU.
What should I do to fix this error?
Thanks